# LyX: use command-alternatives and command-sequence together?

Tags: lyx

I’m trying to make `ctrl+x` have the following function:

1. If there is a selection, cut it.
2. If there is no selection, cut the whole line.

So I tried with the command `command-alternatives cut ; command-sequence line-end; line-begin-select; cut`

However, if there is no selection, the above command stops at the second semicolon (`line-end`), because both `command-alternatives` and `command-sequence` use semicolons to separate LyX functions.

**My question is:** Can `command-alternatives` and `command-sequence` be used together?

Is there a way to fix the command `command-alternatives cut ; command-sequence line-end; line-begin-select; cut`?
Or can I first define a function like `myfunc: command-sequence line-end; line-begin-select; cut`, and then make the binding  `command-alternatives cut ; myfunc`?